# Как добавить псевдоним с помощью телеграм бота

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

Нужно создать телеграм бота для группы который будет перед отправкой сообщения от имени группы  то есть администратора GroupAnonymousBot спрашивать псевдоним для отправителя.
Так как в группе админов несколько не получается понять кто отправил сообщения. Я еще только учусь писать боты по этому буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: А код какой-то уже есть написанный? Или это с нуля надо написать?

Comment: пока не написал,просто не знаю в какую сторону начать идти )

Comment: Изначально создать псевдонимы и привязать к id чата, каждого админа. Редачить админские месседжи после отправки их БОТУ, добавляя подпись.. Бот уже будет постить сообщения в группу с подписью конкретного админа.. Соответственно все админы пишут через бота, а не на прямую в группу. Такой подход даст возможность анализа активности админов и качества их работы..

Comment: а можно сделать так чтобы админы писали на прямую в группу ? типо я пишу сообщения если я админ бот спрашивает у меня псевдоним я от отправляю псевдоним а после уже сообщения

Comment: Получается в группу админ пишет "хочу отправить сообщение" этот месседж залетает в группу, его видят юзеры, бот отвечает админу в их личный чат "погоняло?", или бот это в группу пишет, где все видят, или он должен удалять первичные сообщения, затем спрашивать в личном чате? Всё что админ отправляет в группу сначала постится, затем бот может что-то делать с этими сообщениями при наличии разрешений.. Если бот с админом переписываются в группе это все видят.

Comment: Понял принял спасибо

Comment: На здоровье! :)